# Google cloud load balancer not returning Content-Encoding: gzip

Tags: nginx, load-balancing, http, google-cloud-platform

I'm using google cloud Load balancer that sits in front of an nginx backend service (in google cloud terms).

**When i'm accessing the nginx server directly i can see the 'Content-Encoding: gzip' header (left side).**

**But the response from the Load balancer doesn't contain this header (right side).**

[image]

I've enabled gzip_proxied in my nginx configuration file:

```
server {

   listen 80;
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;  // <------ Here
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/js text/xml text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/xml application/rss+xml image/svg+xml;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        gzip_static on;
        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = "http") {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Relevant link that did not worked:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947469/google-cloud-http-balancer-and-gzip

Any ideas?

Comment: The answer could be found in another thread[1].                                                                             [1]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51932121/google-cloud-load-balancer-not-returning-content-encoding-gzip

Answer (score 1):

I post this community wiki answer to make solution more noticeable.

As it was answered by *@Mohibul Mahmud* at the comment section this question was [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52011385/12428794):

> Cloud load balancer does not compress or decompress responses itself. They serve responses generated by the backend instances that are compressed using [gzip](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/support#compression-not-working).You need to enable [gzip proxied](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_proxied).
>
> In order to contain this header in the load balancer’s response, in you nginx configuration file, you  may have to set up an Accept-Encoding header and modify user agent to contain the string agent as mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/performance).
>
> For example:
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip
>
> User-Agent: my program (gzip)